# What design pattern to use for a method implementation which is repeated in all classes implementing same interface?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I was trying to make an objected oriented examples out of  "union find".

so I have an interface called UF,

```
public interface UF {
    boolean connected(int p,int q);
    void printArray();
    void union(int p,int q);
}
```

and the following classes implement it quickFindUF,quickUnionUF,quickWeightedUnionUF
but all of them share a function which is identical in implementation, (the function printArray())

what is the best pattern to use to avoid printArray() code to be repeated ? do I create a class call ArrayPrinter and pass the array to it in the printArray() in all of those classes which implement UF ?

Is there any pattern that I can do this **without doing abstract inheritance** and just use interfaces. because inheritance limits my design, if I inherit a class I wont be able to inherit anything else, I don't make that limitation just for a printArray() method ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking of [delegation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern). I would personally not call it a design pattern because it's just a compositional technique but anyway there is a Wikipedia article calling it one.

In this example, `UnionFind extends ArrayPrinter` so that the `ArrayPrinter` interface is propagated throughout the composite. The delegate implements a piece of the hierarchy:

```
interface ArrayPrinter {
    void printArray();
}

interface UnionFind extends ArrayPrinter {
    boolean isConnected(int p, int q);
    void makeUnion(int p, int q);
}

class DefaultPrinter implements ArrayPrinter {
    @Override
    public void printArray() {
        /**
         * do actual print
         */
    }
}

class QuickFind implements UnionFind {
    private final ArrayPrinter printDelegate = new DefaultPrinter();

    @Override
    public void printArray() {
        printDelegate.printArray();
    }

    /**
     * the rest
     */
}
```

Comment: Thanks this answered my question, beautifully !

Answer (score 2):

You can have an abstract class AbstractUF like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractUF implements UF{
    public abstract boolean connected(int p,int q);
    public void printArray() {
        //implementation
    }
    public abstract void union(int p,int q);
}
```

and inherit your classes from AbstractUF, so just (override and) implement other 2 functions

Comment: Thanks what is the name of this design pattern ?

Comment: @MedyaGh This is an abstract class. Not everything needs a design pattern.

Comment: is there any pattern that I can do this without doing inheritance and just use interfaces. because inheritance limits my design, if I inherit a class I wont be able to inherit anything else, I don't make that limitation just for a printArray() method ...

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8, you could do it with [Default method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html)

> Interface Methods
>
> Default methods and abstract methods in interfaces are inherited like instance methods. However, when the supertypes of a class or interface provide multiple default methods with the same signature, the Java compiler follows inheritance rules to resolve the name conflict. These rules are driven by the following two principles:
>
> - Instance methods are preferred over interface default methods.
> - Methods that are already overridden by other candidates are ignored. This circumstance can arise when supertypes share a common ancestor.

So your code would be

```
public interface UF {
      default public void printArray() {// Provide default implementation }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any pattern that I can do this without doing abstract inheritance and just use interfaces.

In Java 8, you can declare [default methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) in interfaces.  The limitation is that a default method cannot depend on instance variables declared by implementation classes.  They have to rely entirely on the classes public API to access or update the object state.

For the cases where default methods are applicable, they avoid the need to extend a common base class, while also avoiding the cumbersomeness of delegation.

Answer (score 0):

Interface-segregation principle suggests splitting different functionality into separate interfaces. In this case your `printArray()` method is a responsibility that can be separated from the UF interface.

You implement an `ArrayPrinter` interface and you **pass** arrays to it. This also keeps in line with the single responsibility principle as well as facilities decoupled architecture. You're UF interface doesn't know anything about the printing, that is a separated responsibility so it is handled by a different object.